# How to display partial text from a MySQL column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table `plans`

```
id| plan_name| description
1 | basic    | Good plan for startups <br>
               Excellent quality <br>
               Lorem ipsum Lorem
```

I would like to `echo` only the first two lines from the `description` column using a query in PHP.

**Query**

```
  $getuserplaninfo=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM plans WHERE membershipID='$userplanID'");
  $userplaninforesults=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getuserplaninfo);
  $userplaninfo=$userplaninforesults['description'];
  echo $userplaninfo;
```

**Results should be**

```
Good plan for startups
Excellent quality
```

Comment: What have you tried? In PHP this is pretty easy, are you trying to limit it from mysql though? Also you query should be parameterized and `$userplanID` bound.

Comment: @chris85: I'm trying to limit from PHP.

Comment: try explode it with <br> (explode("<br>", $userplaninfo)) and get first two elements from array

Comment: Have you tried `preg_replace`, `explode`, `preg_match`, `strpos` or any PHP functions though?

Comment: I'd be looking at `SUBSTRING_INDEX ()` because I don't like to ask my DB for more than I need.  What are the actual "rules" that you are applying?  You only want the first two values? Or you don't want the last one?  Can there be more than 3 lines in the string?

Comment: This is the answer I will post if this question gets reopened: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5a55/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with `explode`

```
$userplaninfo = "Good plan for startups <br>
Excellent quality <br>
Lorem ipsum Lorem";
$userplaininfo_array = explode("<br>",$userplaninfo);

$userplaininfo = $userplaininfo_array[0];
if(isset($userplaininfo_array[1]))
{
    $userplaininfo .= "<br>".$userplaininfo_array[1];
}
echo $userplaininfo;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/JEOPW)

Answer (score 0):

You can get sub string using PHP [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

```
$userplaninfo = substr($userplaninforesults['description'], 45);
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but doesn't really answer the question as it was posed. Seems as if the data was delimited in a meaningful way with `<br/>` elements.